# Œuvres critiquant la langue française (comme M. Twain l'a fait pour l'allemand)

Tags: linguistique, littérature, citations

En 1880, Mark Twain l'a surnommé « l'horrible langue allemande », protestant :

> ‘Surely there is not another language that is so slipshod and
> systemless, and so slippery and elusive to the grasp’
>
> (Mark Twain,
> ‘The awful German language’, The Tramp Abroad, 1880 (Harmondsworth:
> Penguin 1997), pp. 390–402).

Voir par exemple :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Awful_German_Language

http://www.twainquotes.com/German.html

Existe-t-il des textes, des citations, des articles, ironiques ou plus sérieux qui critiquent la langue française, sa grammaire, sa syntaxe, etc. ?

Comment: I think I know [just the critic](https://americanliterature.com/author/mark-twain/short-story/the-jumping-frog) for you...

Comment: @LukeSawczak Toujours M. Twain :-)! Merci bien.

Comment: To the extent that a language’s gender bias (or lack thereof) might be included in its “etc.”(if not in its grammar/syntax)  category/aspect, [this article](https://medium.com/au-milieu/war-of-the-words-the-battle-to-make-the-french-language-gender-neutral-7c2329003c9d) does a pretty decent (and neutral, imo) job of providing sources of both serious criticisms of that aspect of the French language as well as some  tongue-in-cheek/mocking reactions to those criticisms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hein ? Comment ? Des critiques de la langue française ?

Certainement pas en français en tout cas. En français, à propos du français... on ne connaît que le mot : **apologie**.

Bon! Trève de balivernes, le french bashing il remonte à loin :

Fénelon (XVIIIe) *la langue française manque de mots, de rythme et de souplesse.*
Pauvreté de vocabulaire également dénoncée par La Bruyère (XVIIe)

Nota : Ces deux-là ne s'exprimaient pas dans l'absolu. Ils s'exprimaient relativement évidemment. Relativement au grec ancien.

Lamartine (XVIIIe),juge les mots français *secs, précis, décolorés, comme des chiffres* (secs... bon... il habitait au bord d'un lac... alors forcément que tout est sec à coté...)

Et je passe évidemment sur les aussi inutiles que méchantes ou jalouses critiques d'outre-manche.

Heureusement que les Allemands (Nietzsche, Heine...) nous ont rendu... ce qui appartenait à César!

Answer (score 4):

On ne trouve pas, et heureusement, de traits aussi sarcastiques à l'égard du français que ceux que l'on trouve à propos de la langue allemande, surtout de la part des Anglophones, comme par exemple:

*« J'ignorais jusqu'ici à quoi servait l'éternité. Ça sert à nous offrir une chance d'apprendre l'allemand. »* (Mark Twain).

*« La vie est trop courte pour apprendre l'allemand! »* (Richard Porson).

*« Lorsque quelqu'un parle allemand, attendre le verbe qu'il va prononcer en fin de phrase est une expérience terrifiante »* (Brian O'Nolan).

Et Churchill conclut en insinuant peut-être que l'âme des peuples est forgée par leur langue:

*« En Angleterre, tout est permis, sauf ce qui est interdit. En Allemagne, tout est interdit, sauf ce qui est permis. En France, tout est permis, même ce qui est interdit. En U.R.S.S., tout est interdit, même ce qui est permis »*

Quant aux critiques de la langue française, nous pouvons conclure qu'elle n'existent pas, de la même façon qu'il est de notoriété publique qu'on situe très bien Gergovie, où les Gaulois ont battu les Romains, mais que personne ne sait où est Alésia, où Vercingétorix capitula devant César...